# Print boolean output of if and else loops

Tags: java, boolean

I have a Java code that checks input from the keyboard.
There is a loop of if that for specific character returns True.
The else returns false for any other character.

How to write a code that identifies which of the above two (True or False) was chosen by the program and print it?
The boolean value of the instance   connectionStatus

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BlueTooth3 {
    public boolean connectionStatus;

     boolean connectBlueTooth () {
        System.out.println("Enter connecting code Baby3");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String conCode = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("You Entered " + conCode);
        keyboard.close();
        if (conCode.equals ("c")){
        System.out.println(conCode + " Is a true Code");
        System.out.println("This is Boolean " +Boolean.TRUE);

            return connectionStatus;
        } 

        if (conCode.equals ("C")){
            System.out.println(conCode + " Is a true Code");
            System.out.println("This is Boolean " +Boolean.TRUE);

                return connectionStatus;
            }
        else {
            System.out.println( conCode + " Is a false Code" );
            System.out.println("This is Boolean " + Boolean.FALSE);
            return connectionStatus;
        }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Why not simply use "System.out.println(connectionStatus);"? It will print the value of the variable and if it's boolean it'll show true or false..

Answer (score 0):

Unless my eyes are closed, you don't seem to be doing anything to the `connectionStatus` variable. You can change the value of that variable so that the function that receives that variable can do things accordingly. For example:

```
    if (conCode.equals ("C")){
        System.out.println(conCode + " Is a true Code");
        System.out.println("This is Boolean " +Boolean.TRUE);
        connectionStatus = true; // means that the code went in this if
            return connectionStatus;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println( conCode + " Is a false Code" );
        System.out.println("This is Boolean " + Boolean.FALSE);
        connectionStatus = false; // means that the code went in this else
        return connectionStatus; 
    }
```

And your code should be something like this:

```
public void myFunc(){
    System.out.println(connectBlueTooth);
}
```

This just simply prints out the outcome of the `connectBlueTooth` function, which should be True if it went in the `if`, and False if it went in the `else`.